# Isolate docker containers from local network but internet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I would like to isolate my docker containers from 192.168.0.x but not from the internet.
That way if the container gets compromised, it can't easily propagate to badly secured devices on the local network or to the host. But the containers must be able to get to the web.

I want the simplest solution possible (docker compose only), no proxy, no iptable ...

Like something like that if it exists @compose.yml

```
networks:
  www_net:
    internal: true
    web: true
```

Comment: Docker compose doesnt provide simplified type. You would have to look at createing a custom docker network